# Search string into all Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to find a string in all the Firebase database (called `myDB`). This string is not in a specific field but it could be in any child. Here an example.

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "dimensions": {
      "height" : 2.1,
      "length" : 12.5,
      "weight": 5000
    }
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "dimensions": {
      "height" : 4,
      "length" : 9,
      "weight" : 2500
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to find the string "15" in all the present fields: `height`, `length`, `weight`.

Considering that in the real case I have a huge number of fields, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Realtime Database doesn't have any sort of global search mechanism.

You'll have to write code that:

1. Reads the entire database into memory, and
2. Recursively descends every key/value pair, checking for the value you want.

If you want a proper search mechanism, mirror your data into a search engine and query that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `lambeosaurus` and `stegosaurus` are direct children of your Firebase root, to check if a string number is equal to one of those values, please use the following method:

```
private void checkValue(String stringToCheck) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.child("dimensions").getChildren()) {
                    int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
                    if(value == Integer.valueOf(stringToCheck)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Value found!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

This will search through each child and will check to see if the any value of the any property within is eaqual to `stringToCheck`.

Comment: Hi Stefano! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?